# Inner Product of center Z(G) of a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G)$ be its center. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define $$J_n=\{(g_1,g_2,...,g_n)\in Z(G)\times Z(G)\times\cdots\times Z(G): g_1g_2\cdots g_n=e\}.$$ As a subset of the direct product group $G \times G \times \dots \times G$
,

$J_n$ is

(1) not necessarily a subgroup,

(2) a subgroup but not necessarily a normal subgroup,

(3) a normal subgroup,

(4) isomorphic to $Z(G)\times Z(G)\times\cdots\times Z(G)$ $((n-1)$ times).

is $J_n$ a subgroup?

> My argument:

let us assume that $n = 2$, then

$J_2 = \{(g_1,g_2)\in Z(G)\times Z(G) :g_1g_2=e\}$ (i.e)

$J_2 = \{(g_1,g_1),(g_1,g_2),(g_2,g_1),(g_2,g_1)\}$ and $g_1g_1= g_1g_2= g_2g_1= g_2g_2=e$

Is this possible? Now consider $Z(G)$

since $g_1$ and $g_2 \in Z(G), g_1g_2=g_2g_1$ and $g_1g_2=g_2g_1 = e$

therefore, $g_1$ is inverse to $g_2$ and vice versa in $Z(G)$, but according to the definition of the set $J_2, g_1g_1=e$ and $g_2g_2=e$ which implies that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are inverses to themselves, but $Z(G)$ is a subgroup every element in it has a unique inverse, hence $J_2$ is not a subgroup....

If there are mistakes in my argument, please tell me where i am wrong...

Comment: In (1)-(3) I assume you mean "a subgroup"...of the cartesian product = direct product $\;G\times G\times\ldots\times G\;$ ?

Comment: You can also write $\bigoplus_i^{n} Z(G)$ to make it easier :) Or use prod!

Comment: @Joanpemo Sorry i cant get you..

Comment: @SamChristopher When you talk of a "subgroup" it is because there is an "overgroup" or larger group in which the assumed subgroup lives, right?

Comment: Yes...You are right...sorry..it is actually a subset of GXGX...G(n times)..To prove that J_n is first of all subgroup of GXGX...G then to prove it is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to show $\;J_n\;$ isn't empty (trivial), and also

$$(g_1,...,g_n),\,\,(h_1,...,h_n)\in J_n\implies (g_1,...,g_n)(h_1,...,h_n)^{-1}\in J_n$$

But assuming what I asked you in my comment above, this is easy:

$$(h_1,...,h_n)^{-1}=(h_1^{-1},...,h_n^{-1})\implies (g_1,...,g_n)(h_1,...,h_n)^{-1}=$$$${}$$

$$=(g_1h_1^{-1},...,g_nh_n^{-1})\in J_n\iff g_1h_1^{-1}\cdot...\cdot g_nh_n^{-1}=1$$

But each and every one of all these elements commute *with everything*, and since also

$$h_1^{-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot h_n^{-1}=(h_1\cdot\ldots\cdot h_n)^{-1}=1^{-1}=1$$
 we thus get
$$g_1h_1^{-1},...,g_nh_n^{-1}=g_1\cdot\ldots\cdot g_n\cdot h_1^{-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot h_n^{-1}=1\cdot1=1$$

So you get (1) and with a very little more work also (3), and thus (2) isn't true, and (4) is true as the last coordinate in $\;J_n\;$ is determined by the first $\;n-1\;$ .

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I got it..please give me the hint to prove that it is a normal subgroup..

Comment: Why is (4) clearly false in the finite case?  The map $(g_1,\ldots, g_{n-1})\mapsto (g_1,\ldots, g_{n-1},(g_1g_2\cdots g_{n-1})^{-1})$ defines a bijection, which looks to be a homomorphism.

Comment: @SamChristopher Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: So you are saying GXGX..G is abelian...how is that? pls explain

Comment: @Aaron In the finite case, the number of elements in both sets is different: they cannot be isomorphic, in my opinion.

Comment: @SamChristopher Oops, I was thinking as a subgroup of Z(G)xZ(G)xZ(G)x...Z(G).

Comment: @Joanpemo Are you sure?  What is the cardinality of $J_2$?

Comment: @SamChristopher The reason it is normal is because for $g \in G, h \in Z(g)$, we have $ghg^{-1}=h$, so if you try to conjugate an element in $J_n$ by an element of $G^n$, you won't change the element (conjugation acts as the identity automorphism, which is a stronger statement than normality).  The same proof gives that $Z(G^n)=Z(G)^n$.  .

Comment: @Aaron Cardinality of J_2 is infinite..I suppose

Comment: @Aaron $\;|J_2|=|Z(G)|^2\;$ , of course. The number of elements in a cartesian product of finite sets is the product of orders of the sets. This is also true in the infinite case but then one can have equalities that don't exist in the finite case, for example $\;\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0\;$, and in fact this is true for any infinite cardinal.

Comment: @Joanpemo That is incorrect.  $|J_2|=|Z(G)|$, as $J_2$ will consist of ordered pairs $(g,g^{-1})$ where $g\in Z(G)$. The point is that the condition for $J_n$, which you appear to be ignoring, implies that the last coordinate is completely determined by the previous coordinates.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you very much, you're completely right: I forgot that and only considered the cartesian product. Editing now.

Comment: @Aaron and Joanpemo: So, what about |J3|? |J3| = |Z(G)XZ(G)| and finally 4th choice is also the right one?

Comment: @SamChristopher (3) and (4) are both right (neither one implies the other).  For (4) you need not just that the cardinalities are the same, but actually that there is an isomorphism between them.  I defined the isomorphism above, you just need to check that it actually is one.